# Is any prime ideal of $K[X_1,...,X_n]$ the intersection of a finite number of maximal ideals?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

If $K$ is an algebraically closed field,
Is any prime ideal of $K[X_1,...,X_n]$ the intersection of a finite number of maximal ideals ?1

Comment: No, take the zero ideal. But even in non-pathological cases, you ask if every irreducible affine variety is a finite set, which is of course wrong in general.

Comment: Isn't it true that if $n>1$ this is never the case for non-maximal primes?

Comment: Liran -- it is.

Comment: You could parse the question differently, and then the answer is "Yes, a maximal ideal is an example of a prime ideal that is the intersection of finitely many maximal ideals."

Comment: In any $T_0$ topological space the only finite irreducible sets are the singletons, hence the only primes satisfying what you want correspond to points i.e., maximal ideals. 

Comment: In $A$ noetherian and $I$ is an ideal, $I$ is an intersection of finitely many maximal ideals iff $A/I$ is artinian and reduced (i.e., a finite product of fields).

Answer (score 8):

In any commutative ring, any ideal that is the intersection of two *other* ideals is *not* prime. Therefore, a prime ideal is the intersection of finitely many maximal ideals if and only if it is itself maximal.